# Hola amigos soy nuevo usando MapKit

Tags: json, ios, xcode, http, macos

Quiero mandar por medio de un slider un radio que selecciona el usuario, y la ubicación del mismo usuario los parámetros latitud y longitud, a una api para que me muestre los lugares cercanos ala úbicacion

[https://aviation-reference-data.p.rapidapi.com/airports/search?rapidapi-key=\(APi_KEY)&lat=19.294261&lon=-99.7014262&radius=100](https://aviation-reference-data.p.rapidapi.com/airports/search?rapidapi-key=%5C(APi_KEY)&lat=19.294261&lon=-99.7014262&radius=100)

Quiero saber cómo obtener esos valores y pasárselo ala api  donde corresponden

Comment: Hola, como eres nuevo, lecturas sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> te muestra el funcionamiento adecuado del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. Aquí recomendaciones de cómo formular preguntas con alto chance de obtención de respuestas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos y bienvenido a estos lares de la red. :D

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.